# I can't use where clause in stored procedure shows error whenever I put where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you tell me what wrong syntax I am having?

I can't use where clause in stored procedure shows error whenever I put where clause.

[image]

Comment: Put code in the post using code blocks, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the Abra says, your syntax is not in the correct order. 
The logical processing order of the SELECT statement is,

1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

However, even though the preceding sequence is usually true, there are uncommon cases where the sequence may differ.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL syntax is wrong. The WHERE must come after the JOIN. For example...

```
select ...
  from A join C on ...
 where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how your query should be written:

```
SELECT *   --<-- replace this with the columns you need
FROM tblProducts A 
INNER JOIN tblBrands C ON C.BrandID = A.PBrandID
CROSS APPLY 
            (
              SELECT TOP 1 *
              FROM tblProductImages B
              WHERE B.PID = A.PID
              ORDER BY B.PID DESC
             ) B
WHERE A.PGender = 1
ORDER BY A.PID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn the basics first of join and usage of where in the join clause.In your example where should be after C.BrandId=A.Brandid or before order by clause